# Release device without reset

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I'm using android management APIs, able to enroll and apply policies to the device.

When I release the device, the device is getting reset, I want to release without reset.

I tried the delete option,

```
def delete_device(device_name):
    # delete a device, which also reformats the device
    result = (androidmanagement.enterprises().devices()
              .delete(name=device_name, wipeDataFlags=['PRESERVE_RESET_PROTECTION_DATA']).execute())
    print('\nDevice deleted: ', result)
    return result
```

even tried without wipeDataFlags argument, device is still getting reset, of course device is de registered.

have tried issuing the RELINQUISH_OWNERSHIP command also

```
def issue_command(device_name, command_type):
    # issue a command to a device
    command = androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().issueCommand(
        name=device_name,
        body={"type": command_type}
    ).execute()
    print('\nCommand issued: ', command)
    return command

def relinquish_ownership(device_name):
    issue_command(device_name, 'RELINQUISH_OWNERSHIP')
```

nothing happens after applying/calling `relinquish_ownership`, even device won't get released.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the behavior of the [devices.delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) method in Android Management API depends on the management mode of the device.

For [company-owned fully-managed](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#company-owned_devices_for_work_use_only) devices and [company-owned, personally-enabled (COPE)](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#company-owned_devices_for_work_and_personal_use) devices, the factory reset upon using devices.delete is the intended behavior.

The [RELINQUISH_OWNERSHIP](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand#CommandType.ENUM_VALUES.RELINQUISH_OWNERSHIP) method you've tried is designed to remove the work profile without resetting the device, but it's specifically applicable to [COPE](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#company-owned_devices_for_work_and_personal_use) devices. This will not work on [fully-managed devices](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#company-owned_devices_for_work_use_only).

The [wipeDataFlags](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete#:%7E:text=Parameters-,wipeDataFlags%5B%5D,-enum%20(WipeDataFlag)) argument controls specific data being wiped (SDCard and Reset Protection data), but the data on the device will still be wiped.

Comment: but i have seen the fully managed device is getting released without reset, when we were using one of the MDM(who uses android management APIs). They deletes the work profile and also releases the device(don't see "This device belongs to your organisation" on lock screen)